# How to update pip version installed by pyenv

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I'm using Python 3.6.5 with pyenv. pip 10 came out a while ago but pyenv is creating my new virtual environments with pip 9.0.3 and i have to update each one of them manually. It's annoying.

I tried to update pyenv and re-installing Python version (i was hoping it will come with newer pip version but it didn't.) but no success.

Should i wait for an update on pyenv side or am i missing something?

Answer (score 11):

Actually pyenv doesn't manage version of pip by default. If you create a virtualenv with virtualenv or pyenv-virtualenv, you end up with the default version of pip. To update the version, you just need to upgrade the pip package with `pip install --upgrade pip`.

EDIT: You can update pip on your python distribution directly if you can and use the virtualenv's flag ‘ --system-site-packages‘ to depend on the system package you have installed previously.

Comment: That's the problem i'm already asking, i don't want to update pip from inside of virtualenv manually, i want pyenv to install them with newest version.

Comment: Actually pyenv doesn't manage version of pip by default. If you create a virtualenv with virtualenv or pyenv-virtualenv, you end up with the default version of pip which is 9.0.3 at the moment (https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/).

Comment: Oh, that's the answer i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I found that I needed to run `python -m pip install -- upgrade pip` instead of `pip install -- upgrade pip` as I do have pyenv shim for pip. So I suppose that if I wanted pip outside of my PYENV, I would update with homebrew or macprots.

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg Your answer is the correct answer.  I'm using pyenv. The shim is not updated when I run `pip install --upgrade <package>` but when I run `python -m pip install --upgrade <package>` then it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a crontab that keeps pip up to date nightly for the three Python vesions I switch between.

```
9 0 * * 0 /Users/userid/.pyenv/shims/python3.9  -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel config >> /tmp/pipupgrade.log
10 0 * * 0 /Users/userid/.pyenv/shims/python3.10  -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel config >> /tmp/pipupgrade.log
11 0 * * 0 /Users/userid/.pyenv/shims/python3.11  -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel config >> /tmp/pipupgrade.log
```