# How to update pip in all environments created by pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyenv

Python warns to update the `pip` version when I try to upgrade `jupyterlab` in my `jupyter3` environment created using `pyenv`. I followed the instructions in the output log:

```
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python3.12 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

when I do it, outside of the environments it doesn't update pip within the `jupyter3` environment. Following the recommendation from: [How to update pip version installed by pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868654/how-to-update-pip-version-installed-by-pyenv) see comment from @JeffreyGoldberg from the answer provided by @TwistedSim it is suggested to run instead:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

but I don't get the `pip` updated inside the environment:

```
dleal:~$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.12.1 (set by /Users/dleal/.pyenv/version)
  3.12.1/envs/jupyter3
* jupyter3 --> /Users/dleal/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/envs/jupyter3 (set by /Users/dleal/.pyenv/version)
```

Now:

```
dleal:~$ pip --version
pip 23.3.1 from /Users/dleal/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)
```

but inside the environment:

```
dleal:~$ pyenv activate jupyter3
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
(jupyter3) dleal:~$ pip --version
pip 23.2.1 from /Users/dleal/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/envs/jupyter3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)
```

**Notes**:

- I am trying to have Python workspace for my new MacBook Air 2023 M2. Following the steps indicated on this link: [The definitive guide to setting up my Python workspace](https://medium.com/@henriquebastos/the-definitive-guide-to-setup-my-python-workspace-628d68552e14) from Henrique Bastos.
- From this SO question: [How can I manually update pip on all pyenv virtualenvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852128/how-can-i-manually-update-pip-on-all-pyenv-virtualenvs) the answer suggested by @phd is to do a `for`-loop, but I guess there should be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: as I know every environment should have own folder with `python` and `pip` and you can use `/full/path/to/this/pip ...` to install or update modules only in selected environment.

Comment: Thanks, @furas, but if I set as global Python version and the `jupyter3` environment I was expecting to get it updated since it is the global (common) environment. I am not an expert, so maybe I am wrong. Doing it on each environment seems to me a very manual process.

Comment: global environment doesn't update other environments. This is main idea of using virtual environments. This way every environment can use different versions. Some projects may need older modules, other the newest. But you can always write script which will update some elements in all environment. For example when I create new `venv` then I always use subfolder `.venv` and I had script which searchs all folders `.venv` on disk (and it keeps in file) and it can run every `.venv/bin/pip` to update it, BTW: in similar way I work with Git repos - I search all folders `.git` on disk, etc.

Comment: Thanks @furas, I am looking at the list of [pyenv-plugins](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Plugins) maybe some specific one can be used for a similar purpose. For example [pip-upgrade](https://github.com/zyrikby/pyenv-pip-upgrade), but I haven't dug into it, there are several of them with a similar purpose, but I think with this one you can specify a specific package. I need to research more in this option. It seems it updates all the package, not a specific one, but it may work.

Comment: After some research, some packages are outdated, lack maintenance, or don't work for macOs, only for Ux. I guess [pipupgrade](https://pypi.org/project/pipupgrade/) is the most complete one, I haven't tested it I guess it should work to update environments and it allows to specify the packages to update, etc.. @furas would be possible for you to share your script? Thanks